# update javax json from 1.0.2 to 1.1

Tags: java, json

I'm developing a project that uses Tomcat7 and uses javax.json. Until now everything worked, but now I updated the javax.json from 1.0.2 to 1.1 and when I start the tomcat gives me the following error:

```
jun 27, 2017 10:12:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig processAnnotationsJar
SEVERE: Unable to process Jar entry [module-info.class] from Jar [jar:file:/D:/projectx/projectxFull/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat%207.0/webapps/standard/WEB-INF/lib/javax.json-1.1.jar!/] for annotations
org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 19
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.Constant.readConstant(Constant.java:133)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ConstantPool.<init>(ConstantPool.java:60)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.readConstantPool(ClassParser.java:209)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.parse(ClassParser.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2134)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:2010)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1976)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1961)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1319)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:878)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:376)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5322)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:983)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1660)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

jun 27, 2017 10:12:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://example.com/custom_tags is already defined
jun 27, 2017 10:12:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt is already defined
jun 27, 2017 10:12:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core is already defined
jun 27, 2017 10:12:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core is already defined
jun 27, 2017 10:12:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt_rt is already defined
jun 27, 2017 10:12:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt is already defined
jun 27, 2017 10:12:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt is already defined
jun 27, 2017 10:12:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions is already defined
jun 27, 2017 10:12:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/permittedTaglibs is already defined
jun 27, 2017 10:12:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/scriptfree is already defined
jun 27, 2017 10:12:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql_rt is already defined
jun 27, 2017 10:12:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql is already defined
jun 27, 2017 10:12:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql is already defined
jun 27, 2017 10:12:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml_rt is already defined
jun 27, 2017 10:12:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml is already defined
jun 27, 2017 10:12:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml is already defined
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/D:/ProjectX/projectxFull/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat%207.0/webapps/standard/WEB-INF/lib/com.springsource.slf4j.log4j-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/D:/ProjectX/projectxFull/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat%207.0/webapps/standard/WEB-INF/lib/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
jun 27, 2017 10:12:14 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
log4j:WARN Error during default initialization
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/mail/util/MailLogger
    at javax.mail.Session.initLogger(Session.java:230)
    at javax.mail.Session.<init>(Session.java:214)
    at javax.mail.Session.getInstance(Session.java:251)
    at org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender.createSession(SMTPAppender.java:225)
    at org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender.activateOptions(SMTPAppender.java:137)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.activate(PropertySetter.java:307)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:172)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:104)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseAppender(PropertyConfigurator.java:809)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:735)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configureRootCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:615)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:502)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:547)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(OptionConverter.java:483)
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:127)
    at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:73)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:242)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:156)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:132)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:272)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:301)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:983)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1660)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.mail.util.MailLogger
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
    ... 35 more
jun 27, 2017 10:12:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
jun 27, 2017 10:12:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: You cannot use a spring-security-2.0.xsd or spring-security-3.0.xsd or spring-security-3.1.xsd schema or spring-security-3.2.xsd schema or spring-security-4.0.xsd schema with Spring Security 4.2. Please update your schema declarations to the 4.2 schema.
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.fatal(FailFastProblemReporter.java:60)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.fatal(ReaderContext.java:68)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.fatal(ReaderContext.java:55)
    at org.springframework.security.config.SecurityNamespaceHandler.parse(SecurityNamespaceHandler.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1411)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1401)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:172)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:142)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:94)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:392)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:614)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:515)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:443)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:325)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:983)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1660)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

jun 27, 2017 10:12:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
jun 27, 2017 10:12:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/standard] startup failed due to previous errors
jun 27, 2017 10:12:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
jun 27, 2017 10:12:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStop
SEVERE: Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.getBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:170)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1030)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:958)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:583)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4980)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5626)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:983)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1660)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

What I can do now?

Thank you

Comment: Which Java version are you using? Maybe version 1.1 of that library requires a newer version of Java than what you are using.

Comment: I'm using jdk1.8.0_111

Answer (score 3):

Thanks tigger, for pointing that out. This was causing an Exception for me in Wildfly-10.1.0.Final when I deployed: "Could not index class module-info.class"

I didn't want to go back versions, so I "fixed" the jar:

Move the jar to its own directory

```
cd that directory
```

explode the javax.json-1.1.jar file:

```
jar xvf javax.json-1.1.jar
```

deleting module-info.class

```
rm module-info.class
```

Get rid of the jar itself

```
rm javax.json-1.1.jar
```

Put everything back in the jar:

```
jar cvf javax.json-jdk8-1.1.jar .
```

Move the jar back to where you need it to build from.

note: since I added "jdk8" to the name of the jar to distinguish it from the maven repo version, I also had to update my build paths everywhere that uses it.

Rebuild, re-deploy, voila! No more Wildfly errors! :)

Comment: Great! Thank you! It worked perfectly, on tomcat 8, too

Answer (score 2):

I have encountered the same problem. In my case, the javax.json 1.1 is build with JDK9 ea; the tell-tale sign is [module-info.class]. After changing to the older version, my war file is deployed by Tomcat without complain.

Answer (score 2):

1. Downloaded Jersey compliant to javax.ws.rs-api-2.1
2. Below jars were downloaded with corrupt module-info.class

   javax.json.bind-api-1.0

   javax.json-1.1

   javax.json-api-1.1

   yasson-1.0

[image: DeCompiled these jars with Java Decompiler]

3. Added these jars (among other Jersey jars) to build path of RESTful Web App

   Used JAVAEE6

   Tried JDK 1.7 and 1.8 both
4. Deployed using NetBeans in Tomcat 8.0.27.0
5. Got this error

   09-May-2018 18:17:06.298 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar Unable to process Jar entry [module-info.class] from Jar [jar:file:/D:/***/build/web/WEB-INF/lib/javax.json-api-1.1.jar!/] for annotations
   org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 19

   09-May-2018 18:17:06.361 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar Unable to process Jar entry [module-info.class] from Jar [jar:file:/D:/***/build/web/WEB-INF/lib/javax.json-1.1.jar!/] for annotations
   org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 19

   09-May-2018 18:17:06.892 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar Unable to process Jar entry [module-info.class] from Jar [jar:file:/D:/***/build/web/WEB-INF/lib/javax.json.bind-api-1.0.jar!/] for annotations
   org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 19

   09-May-2018 18:17:07.233 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar Unable to process Jar entry [module-info.class] from Jar [jar:file:/D:/***/build/web/WEB-INF/lib/yasson-1.0.jar!/] for annotations
   org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 19

Now i am downloading above jars separately to get error free jars

Answer (score 1):

I too faced the same problem when I was using java 1.8 with JAXRS-RI 2.27 and Tomcat 8.5 Version. Then i have removed those old 2.27 jars from /WEB-INF/lib folder and removed from buildpath as well. Then replaced with jaxrs-ri-2.6 jars in lib and project buildpath. This solution helped me.

Download this: jaxrs-ri-2.6.zip from [this Link](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/jersey/bundles/jaxrs-ri/2.6/).